# Bar chart on specified data

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, charts

I want to make a chart bar, using mysql and json data, and I want the datasets to work like this:

```
var data = {
  labels: [dateLoop], #ignore this
  datasets: [{ 
    label :  (Json["data"][0])    
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",    
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",    
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",    
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    data: [(value orderby month in Json["data"][0]]           
  },    
  { label :  (Json["data"][1])    
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",    
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",    
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",    
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",    
    data: [(value orderby month in Json["data"][1]]           
  }    
]};
```

Can anyone do this? I just asked this in another post, but no one understands what I want.

Comment: nope, you've posted (incomplete or maybe invalid syntax) data, then asked how to make this code work, but there is no code, if you need help debugging code (which your question implies) you'll need to post the code you need help with

Comment: @JaromandaX what i mean, i need looping on dataset : label. Any idea how i'm looping dataset : label???

Comment: let me ask this ... what is it that you have posted in the "code block" in the question? an actual dataset you get from something? some pseudo code? I don't even know how to read that, because it's not javascriipt, it's not mysql, it's not json and it isn't "charts" - if you want an answer on SO, you need to be CLEAR in your question, show what you've tried, show exact format of input data, and expected output data (no, don't show a graph, show how the data should be formatted for the graph to use)

Comment: Improved title; collapsed formatting on code.